# gnome-terminal not openning in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, gnome

Terminal does not open in Ubuntu 20.04, this is possibly after an upgrade of the software (apt upgrade). I am getting the following error when trying to execute /usr/bin.gnome-terminal in a xterm.

```
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real: error while loading shared libraries: libvte-2.91.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

libvte-2.91-dev, libvte-2.91-0, libvte-2.91-common packages are already installed. But there is not file named libvte-2.91.so.0 as the error mentioned.

Any help to resolve this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Try sudo apt autoremove then restart and run update again.

Comment: From `recovery mode` - Does this run smoothly, without error; `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` ?

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
$ locate libvte-2.91.so.0
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvte-2.91.so.0
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvte-2.91.so.0.5200.2
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvte-2.91.so.0
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvte-2.91.so.0.5200.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvte-2.91.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvte-2.91.so.0.6000.3
    
$ cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

$ ls -l libvte-2.91.so.0*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 jun 11  2020 libvte-2.91.so.0 -> libvte-2.91.so.0.6000.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 506088 jun 11  2020 libvte-2.91.so.0.6000.3

$ sha256sum libvte-2.91.so.0.6000.3
6fed2cc3f15b5c77570ae57301a23e140db1f5afc533d91fe29da3359c51397a  libvte-2.91.so.0.6000.3
$
```

So these
`$ cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`
`$ sudo ln -s libvte-2.91.so.0.6000.3 libvte-2.91.so.0`
... MIGHT fix your problem.

Oh, and `locate` is from `sudo apt install mlocate && sudo updatedb`

... and as you've already noted, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvte-2.91.so.0`
is from `sudo apt install --reinstall libvte-2.91-0`